# Spring bean-scopes

Tags: java, web-services, spring, spring-mvc, spring-ws

Hi I have a soap web service(java, spring, tomcat)

In my web.xml file i have a reference to MessageDispatcherServlet and this is how my servlet.xml file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    
xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans       
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

<description></description>

<bean id="payloadMapping"

class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootQNameEndpointMapping">
    <property name="defaultEndpoint" ref="inferenceEndPoint" />
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <ref local="validatingInterceptor" />
            <ref local="payLoadInterceptor" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
.
.
.
```

Now I want to use spring's **request scope** beans, what are the steps for creating this bean? how many different classes I have to create and how do I have to modify my xml files. For using session scope I read somewhere that:

*"in order to use session scope, you have to be using a web-aware Spring application context, such as XmlWebApplicationContext. Otherwise there's no way for the scoped proxy to reference a current session"*

Do I need something like this also for using request scope?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have `dispatcher-servlet.xml` (that's the default name) so you have a `WebApplicationContext`. Now you only need to define `<bean scope="request"` or `scope="session"`

If using annotations, you can use `@Scope("request")`. Also note that request and session-scoped beans are used more rarely than singleton scoped beans.

Comment: Thanks, and how many classes do I have to create? in this link it describes how to create session scope and he creates 4 classes:  a controller, a service interface, a service implementation, and a model class. do have to create these classes and could you check if the xml file will be the same other than changing the scope name? http://wheelersoftware.com/articles/spring-session-scoped-beans.html

Comment: well, that depends entirely on what you want to do with it. The session bean requires only one class. The other 3 are for the whole functionality across all layers.

Comment: and referring to the xml in the example in the link is this correct?: confused about the proxy thing      <bean id="shoppingCart"     class="ssbexample.ShoppingCart" scope="request">
        <!-- This requires CGLIB -->
        <aop:scoped-proxy/>
    </bean>